# Read correct data received in UDP connection

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

I wrote an app in c# .net 4.0 on windows 7 64 bit.
The app is listening to UDP data on a specific port and I'm trying to determine the Host IP of the requester with the help of Windows DNS. To do this I'll need the correct URL on the UDP information I receive but I cannot get it correctly due to lots of garbage and inconsistency of the message(lack of a format).
This is the code for listening on UDP requests:

```
public void StartListener()
{
    m_udpClient = new UdpClient(53);
    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 53);

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] bytes = m_udpClient.Receive(ref groupEP);
            Console.WriteLine("UDPListener::StartListener Waiting for broadcast");
            string udpData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("UDPListener::StartListener Received broadcast from {0} :\n {1}\n",
                groupEP.ToString(), udpData);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("UDPListener::StartListener UDP server stopped!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

The code is working fine it's receiving data on udpData, but it's with a lot of garbage and I cannot find a way to extract only the necessary info. A sample on what I am receiving:
 ???  ?      ?www?google?com  ? ?
a second message:
 "\0\0\0\0spsprodch1su1dedicatedsb2\nservicebus\awindowsnet\0\0\0"
Do you have any idea on how I can get valid info from that data? THX

Comment: Isnt the problem that you are encoding it with ASCII when you should be using UTF8?

Comment: UTF8 gives me the same result as ASCII and as Default, there is a big amount of data in the received message that is not unicode or ascii, just random bytes from my point of view.

Comment: Hm where do you get this data from anyways? Also try this Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); Even tho this should not change anything

Comment: I think it is clear that the **sender** is sending garbage.

Answer (score 1):

`UdpClient.Receive` just returns the UDP datagram sent by the peer. Since you are using port 53 I assume you are expecting DNS queries. In this case you cannot simply treat this UDP datagram as a string, but you must parse the datagram as a DNS packet, see [RFC1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) for the packet format.